# How to have one Flask app listen on two different ports?

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to have a single flask app with routes on two different ports? My Flask app needs to listen for webhooks and due to some security biz it can't receive foreign POST requests on the default port. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
@app.route('/hook/<sourcename>', methods=["POST"], port=5051)
def handle_hook(sourcename):
  print 'asdf'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server by default only listens to a single port. Wouldn't it make more sense, since the additional port requires additional functionality, to implement a front-end server on the second port that proxies the POST request locally? There are many well-documented ways to do this [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443260/multiple-backend-servers-accessible-from-a-flask-server)

Comment: I think this makes the best sense.  It seems to be the common pattern nowadays to let the application (flask app) focus on the function of the service.  The proxy/gateway will be responsible for paths and security.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need any socket code inside C plugins, gevent could help, e.g. with

```
import gevent
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

app = Flask(__name__)

https_server = WSGIServer((HOST, HTTPS_PORT), app, keyfile=PRIVKEY, certfile=CERT)
https_server.start()

http_server = WSGIServer((HOST, HTTP_PORT), app)
http_server.start()

while True:
    gevent.sleep(60)
```

Comment: If understood right from documentation requests will be processed one at a time with this solution even if they are directed to different ports.