# Listening to multiple ports in socket io flask

Tags: python, sockets, flask

Following is the code that I have for the socket server in node js

```
let express = require("express");
let http_server = require("http").Server(express());
let io_server = require("socket.io")(http_server);

let app = express();
let http_publisher = require("http").Server(app);
let io_publisher = require("socket.io")(http_publisher);
.
.
.
http_server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("WebSocket: listening on *:3000");
});

http_publisher.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log("HTTP server: listening on *:3001")
});
```

what is the python equivalent of the same code? I have tried the following  but it just wont let me listen to two ports at the same time :(

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('my event')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': 'got it!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,port=3000)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have one Flask app listen on two different ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760549/how-to-have-one-flask-app-listen-on-two-different-ports)

Comment: Unfortunately No.... I have tried it too :(

Comment: Did you try the second answer?

Comment: I have tried it. It doesn't allow us to plug in the socketio.

Comment: Is this for development? Otherwise you could just throw nginx or similar in front of it and have it open two or more ports.

Comment: @eandersson could you please explain how i do that?

Comment: I used waitress to do so. I'm getting ` An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

Comment: For using nginx you can take a look at this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04 or https://medium.com/faun/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-7fda4f50066a