# Can a React app communicate with Flask and express backend both at once?

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a React app with a Flask backend listening to port 5000 in `localhost` (default for Flask). Could I add another backend using express for the same web-app that listens to port 5000 too? I know there is no need for another express backend since everything can be achieved in Flask or express itself, but I wanted to try making multiple backends work from the same frontend.

To be clear, my use case is something like this:

1. User sends a `POST` request to Flask, which saves the data in a local db.
2. Use that saved value (response from Flask) from the local db to do more stuff in the express server.
3. Use the response from express server to redirect user to appropriate page in React.

Most tutorials online have only one backend, but I wanted to work with a more complex system. I was thinking of an idea something along the lines of -

1. From React, call `fetch('flask/api/save'` and save the data in the Flask backend calling `@app.route('flask/api/save')` where it saves the data in a local db.
2. Once we get a successful response from the Flask backend, call another `fetch('express/api/doWork)`, where I use the same port 5000 to connect to the local db that was updated in Flask, from express using `app.get('/express/api/doWork)` and send an appropriate response.
3. Redirect user to the correct page based on the response.

Is this even possible? Or is there a better way to achieve this communication?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer myself. It's not possible for 2 servers to listen on the same port. The solution here would be to use Flask as a reverse proxy and redirect the client calls to the express server.

Reference - [Multiple backend servers accessible from a Flask server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443260/multiple-backend-servers-accessible-from-a-flask-server)